# Slick filter when comparing value and column is Option

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

have  a table where `formDefinitionId` is nullable column in Postgres DB (9.3) . Slick version is 2.1.0

we have a this filter on a query

```
table.filter(_.formDefinitionId === request.formDefinitionId)
```

`request.formDefinitionId` where `request` is nothing but a Scala `case class` with `formDefinitionId` as an `Option[Int]`

```
case class Request(formDefinitionId : Option[Int])
```

now when `request.formDefinitionId` is `None` slick generates following query

```
(x2."form_definition_id" = null)
```

vs

```
(x2."form_definition_id” IS NULL) - this is what Postgres expects
```

Work around is to create a different filter based on `request.formDefinitionId`

e.g.

```
request.formDefinitionId match {
  case Some(fid) => table.filter(_.formDefinitionId === fid)
  case None => table.filter(_.formDefinitionId.isNull)
}
```

however creating such condition for every property which is `Option` isn't feasible - there exists numerous `Option` properties across many tables. Is there a better/generic way to achieve this? I would imagine this is a common scenario with people using Slick

Comment: @EndeNeu : difference is in postgres behavior. when you pass in IS NULL in postgres query it'll return result with the rows that have that column empty . however when query has =null query doesn't return anything

Comment: Sorry, was a stupid question, I didn't realize the actual difference.

Comment: You want `.isEmpty`. We should probably throw an exception when you try to use a real null value in a query.

Comment: @szeiger : sorry didn't get you. I think you're referring to .isEmpty for a work around snippet I pasted inside match? I am still not sure how to address this "table.filter(_.formDefinitionId === request.formDefinitionId)" when request.formDefitionId can be None or Some(id) . again on table "formDefinitionId" column it's "val formDefinitionId: Column[Option[Int]]" - "request.formDefinitionId" is the value coming in from a model case class as described in my post

Comment: also see https://www.google.com/search?q=slick+option+compare&oq=slick+option+compare   there are lots of related discussions. At the core: Slick uses 3-valued logic and None is interpreted as false, if you want more preciseness use isEmpty.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test (I don't have a Slick setup here).

But as `= null` returns nothing, shouldn't something like this work?

```
 table.filter(r => r.formDefinitionId.isNull || r.formDefinitionId === fid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution with Slick 3.3.x:

```
table
  // case 1: both are empty
  .filterIf(request.formDefinitionId.isEmpty)(_.formDefinitionId.isEmpty)
  // case 2: both are defined and equal
  .filterOpt(request.formDefinitionId)(_.formDefinitionId === _)
```

case 1 corresponds the following SQL:

```
 select * from table1 when form_definition_id is null;
```

case 2:

```
 select * from table1 when form_definition_id = ?;
```

Answer (score -1):

I am a newer to slick and now also confused with this problem. Maybe it's toolate to you.I wanted to do some search with different column(Option[text]). Here is my code ,It is worked to me.

```
val someone1 = cou.filter(_.id === id_S)

val someone2 = cou.filter(_.first_name === first)

val someone3 = cou.filter(_.last_name === last)

val someone = (someone1) union (someone2) union (someone3)

dbConfig.db.run(someone.result).map(_.toList)
```